# Putting random spaces in a dynamic grid

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of words that dynamically generate a grid.

The problem is I need a 6x6 grid and if there is not enough words in the list to facilitate a 6x6 (12 words) then it won't.

How can I make it so it always produces a 6x6 grid, randomly generates positions for the words and fills the gaps with empty cells?

```
var listOfWords = ["mat", "cat", "dog", "pit", "pot", "fog"];
var shuffledWords = listOfWords.slice(0).sort(function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
}).slice(0, 6);
var tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.className = 'tablestyle';
var wordsPerRow = 2;
for (var i = 0; i < shuffledWords.length; i += wordsPerRow) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = i; j < i + wordsPerRow; ++j) {
        var word = shuffledWords[j];
        for (var k = 0; k < word.length; k++) {
            var cell = document.createElement('td');
            cell.textContent = word[k];
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }
    tbl.appendChild(row);
}
document.body.appendChild(tbl);
```

Comment: Ye sorry forgot to take them out @joeshmo

Comment: @joeshmo yes, but it also needs to be easily adaptable

Comment: Fill the array with `&nbsp;` to the max amount of cells needed

Comment: How to you mean? ..http://jsfiddle.net/e5BKq/1/ @GeenHenk

Comment: are words always 3 letters long ? do you always want 2 words per row ?

Comment: @Steve, did you write this code?

Comment: @Tom yes they are always 3 letters long but sometimes there can be 0,1 or 2 words per row. I need 6 words in a 12 word grid in random positions each time, thanks

Comment: Check the **EDIT2** in my answer. It picks 6 random words and fills a 6x6 grid with the words and random spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5BKq/23/)

I added:

```
while(listOfWords.length < 6)
    listOfWords.push("   ");
```

So if there are not enough words, it appends the array with empty 'words' (3 spaces) and that gets shuffled, which results in random blank spaces

---

**EDIT**

[JSFiddle with 12 words](http://jsfiddle.net/e5BKq/27/)

**EDIT2**

I think this is what you want:
[JSFiddle with 6 words, filled with spaces](http://jsfiddle.net/e5BKq/32/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function loaded() {
                    var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
                if(tbl != null) {
                    tbl.parentNode.removeChild(tbl);
                }
                var nrOfWordsToUse = Number(document.getElementById("howManyWords").value);
                if(nrOfWordsToUse > 12 || nrOfWordsToUse < 0) {
                    alert("nrOfWordsToUse has to be between 0 and 12");
                } else {
                    var initialListOfWords = ["mat", "cat", "dog", "pit", "pot", "fog", "aha", "beb", "pan", "pet", "pir", "pem"];
                    listOfWords = [];
                    for(var i = 0; i < nrOfWordsToUse; i++)
                        listOfWords[i] = initialListOfWords[i];
                    var positions = [];
                    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                        positions[i] = ["", "", "", "", "", ""];
                    }
                    for(var i = 0; i < listOfWords.length; i++) {
                        var y = number0to5();
                        var x = number0or3();
                        if(positions[y][x] == "") {
                            positions[y][x] = listOfWords[i].charAt(0);
                            positions[y][x + 1] = listOfWords[i].charAt(1);
                            positions[y][x + 2] = listOfWords[i].charAt(2);
                        } else {
                            i--;
                        }
                    }
                    var table = document.createElement("table");
                    table.id = "tbl";
                    document.body.appendChild(table);
                    for(var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
                        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                        for(var j = 0; j < positions[i].length; j++) {
                            var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                            cell.innerHTML = positions[i][j];
                        }
                    }
                }
                alert("end");
            }
            function number0to5() {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
            }
            function number0or3() {
                return Math.random() > 0.5 ? 0 : 3;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="howManyWords" value="6" /><input type="button" onclick="loaded()" value ="doIt"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dpbzq/12/

---

About your request to help you build in my code into yours:

I made a new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uv74h/2/

As you can see, it is a function: rndSpaces. It takes 1 parameter; an array of 3-letter words, with a maximum of 12 words. They don't have to be pre-shuffled; the function will shuffle them. The function will try to find a table with id == "myTable". If it doesn't find the table it creates a table and appends it to a div with id == "myDiv" (There is one line commented out; if you want to append it to the body, uncomment that line and comment out the line that appends the table to the div). The function clears everything in the table, creates a 6x6 grid and fills it with the words. I gave the table, rows and cells a css style (tablestyle, myRow and myCell).

this is an example of the function getting called:

```
rndSpaces(["pim", "pam", "pet", "rol", "fik", "fak", "ral"]);​
```

Comment: But how do I specify how many I want to pull from the list? @Tom

Comment: I made an edit; now you I have twelve words defined and there's a text box; you can put a number from 0 to 12; that's how many words will be used.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need, but I cannot apply it to my code can you help? http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/bEYJH/11/ @Tom

Comment: Maybe...I'll write you a function if you do your best to explain to me exactly what it has to do; you can start with coming up with a meaningfull name and parameters for this function.

Comment: var rndSpaces for every word in table produce 3 empty cells so there is 6, 3 letter words and 18 empty cells @Tom